# Regular Expressions with bat file

Tags: regex, batch-file, replace

I have few replacement using regex. For now I was using TextCrawler, but now I would like to do those replacement with bat file.

Could You help me make a syntax of my replacement so this bat file will do replacements  in .txt files:

.*first_text.*
replace with:
example1

.*secomd_text.*
replace with:
example2

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/2861476)

Comment: Thanks mate but this is too much information for me. anything simplest

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir)

Comment: Just do it with 'sed' from the GnuWin32 project.

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with PowerShell. It can do regular expression search and replace and is a far more powerful and expressive language than cmd.exe shell script (batch).

Answer (score 0):

Bill Stewart is right in this instance.  The simplest answer without requiring a script or 3rd party utility is to use a PowerShell one-liner.  To do a replacement in a single text file:

```
powershell "(gc textfile.txt) -replace '.first_text', 'example1' | sc textfile.txt"
```

To search and replace in all text files in the current directory:

```
powershell "gci *.txt | %{ (gc $_) -replace '.first_text', 'example1' | sc $_ }"
```

Or you could use [`jrepl.bat`](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) as MC ND suggests.  Or you could use [GnuWin32 `sed`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) as Endoro suggests.